# Node.js Connection terminated before query is finished

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express

Newbie with node.js.
I have set up an Node/express server on a Windows Server hosting a `PostgreSQL` database.
My goal is to insert in the database the data from a **csv** file choosen by a user on its own computer, using a HTML form.

Here is the part of the js file executed after the user submits the form:

```
app.post('/envoi', upload.single("fichiercsv"), async(req, res) => {
let newClient
try {
    const { identifiant, motdepasse } = req.body
    const clientConfigModifie = {
    ...clientConfigDefaut,
    user: identifiant,
    password: ''
    }
    newClient = new Client(clientConfigModifie)
        
    await newClient.connect()
     
    const rows = []
    const buffer = req.file.buffer
        // console.log(buffer) //ok
    const readableStreamFromBuffer = new stream.Readable()
    readableStreamFromBuffer.push(req.file.buffer)
    readableStreamFromBuffer.push(null)
    await new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        fastcsv.parseStream(readableStreamFromBuffer, { headers: false })
            .on('data', us => {
                rows.push(us)   
            })
            .on('end', async() => { 
                rows.shift()
                const usTotal = rows.map( us => us.join("").split(";"))
                // console.log(us)
                for (const us of usTotal) {
                await newClient.query("insert into activite.us (numus, gidgeo) VALUES ($1, $2)", [us[0], us[13]])
                })
                resolve()
            })
            .on("error", error => console.error(error))
        })  
}   
catch(e) {
    console.log("erreur lors du traitement", e)
    res.send(`<h3>échec de la connexion</h3>`)
}
finally {
    try {
        newClient.end()
    }
    catch(e) { 
        console.log(e) 
    }
}
})
```

- If I omit the `finally` part, the data are inserted in the database, but the connection is running...
- With the `finally` part, only the **first** row of `us` is inserted. Thus, I have the message :

`error: Connection terminated at C:\Apache\balbla\`

In this case, it seems that `newClient.query` runs one time only then for some reason the connection is terminated but not ended.
What am I doing wrong ?

*EDIT* : code updated after @I2yscho answer.

Comment: newClient.query is also async operation, you need to await it or use Promise.all to make it work. Btw it is not good idea to insert records in loop.

Comment: You are right : `newClient.query` is asynchrone. So map() has to be replaced by a for of. I updated the code. Thx. What do you suggest instead of a loop?

Comment: If your ORM does not any bulk insert operation, try at least build only one Insert statement (SQL insert can add multiple item in one query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is you don't handle insert operations asynchronously. This code is not a best way how to handle this, but it is working solution. I recommend you to use some sort of bulk insert in one query.

```
.on('end', () => {
            rows.shift();
            const usData = rows.map(us => us.join("").split(";"));
            
            const insertPromises = usData.map(us => {
                return newClient.query("INSERT INTO activite.us (numus, gidgeo) VALUES ($1, $2)", [us[0], us[13]]);
            });

            Promise.all(insertPromises)
                .then(() => {
                    resolve();
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    reject(error);
                });
        })
```

Comment: I posted my answer before seeing yours...ok for the bulk insert concept. It makes sense. I try that and will be back to update the code if I can find something efficient.

Comment: I used [pg-format](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg-format) to handle bulk insert.